# real analysis of a taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have a random function $f(x)$. I know nothing about the shape of the function, but I know

- $f'(x)$ exists, $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- $f(3)=1$, $f'(3)=5$, $f''(3)=7, f''''(3)=-3$
- $-3\leq f''(x)\leq 9,  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
- $-4 \leq f'''(x) \leq -1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

So having this information, I built $T_{2, 3}=1+5(x-3)^{1}+7\frac{(x-3)^{2}}{2}$ for this function.

But, how do we find the upper bound for the error using $T_{2,3}$ for f(5)? Using taylor's remainder theorem is fine but which points should I choose for $f'''(c)$? I don't have an interval to work with, which is confusing.

Comment: There are no such functions!  Since $f'''(x)\leq -1$ for all $x$ you must have $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f''(x)=\mp\infty$ violating the bound on $f''(x)$.